# Only returning rows when there is a certain count of a given column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a `SELECT` query which only returns rows when a column (call it `My_Column`) has only one distinct value, that is when `COUNT(DISTINCT My_Column) = 1`.  If there are multiple distinct values of `My_Column`, I don't want any rows returned. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.my_column) = 1
```

Be aware of how [MySQL handles GROUP BY and HAVING with Hidden Columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).

Comment: NP, I'm sure you would have caught it but it made me nuts so I jumped on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM table a
WHERE 1 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT My_Column) FROM table);
```

Comment: That'll return a cartesian product because there's no join criteria

Comment: @OMGPonies, im not returning anything from b, just return from a if b.bount=1.

Comment: @Neal - there's no join criteria so it will return only ONE row, since b will only be a single `COUNT` value

Comment: @Neal - there's still no `GROUP BY` so it'll only return a single row.  The edited query will only have results if there is only one value for `My_Column` in the whole table.

Comment: @JNK. I am now using the second select as a filter. it will now not only return one row. It should work just as planned

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ...
GROUP BY foo
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT My_Column) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(My_Column), My_Column FROM tbl GROUP BY My_Column HAVING COUNT(My_Column)=1
```